# Javascript/jquery code for finding ancestor text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <h3>
      <a> Text </a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="clickme"> click me </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is onclick of class "clickme" i want to print Text.I also don't want to add any more classes in any div.

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Take a look at HTML DOM Element Object https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: I would use the methods `.closest()` and `.querySelector()` and the `.textContent` property.

Comment: @deltab please provide the answer.I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to [traverse the DOM](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) using jQuery. Here are two examples (one in jQuery and one in vanilla JS) that may work for your situation:

```js
// Using jQuery
$(".clickme").on("click", function (e) {
  console.log($(".parent a").first().text());
});

// Using vanilla JS
document.querySelector(".clickme").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  console.log(document.querySelector(".parent a").innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <h3>
      <a> Text </a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="clickme">
    click me
   </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the get the text using `.text()` in jQuery like below

```
$('.parent > div > h3 > a').text()
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickme', function(e) {
  console.log($('.parent > div > h3 > a').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <h3>
   <a> Text </a>
  </h3>
 </div>
<div>
   <ul>
  <li>
   <a class="clickme">
    click me
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```